# Delete all lines with

Tags: notepad++

I know there are already tutorials on how to delete lines with a certain text but I think the text I choose is conflicting with something which is why it doesn't work.

So I would like to delete all lines with the following text:
`Cost: 0$`

I am using Notepad++.

Comment: Just escape the `\$` if you are using `$` in the regex.

Comment: Whats the conflict?

Comment: @Striker I have no idea what the conflict is, I said "I _think_ the text I choose is conflicting"

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I still do not know how to delete all lines with "Cost: 0$"

Comment: What pattern and settings do you use?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't know. But I normally use Regular Expression. I don't know how Regular Expression works though. I just need a Expression to put into the "Find what:" text field that will select the whole line if it contains: "Cost: 0$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you selected *Regular Expressions* check box in the Search and Replace dialog, and use

```
.*Cost: 0\$.*\R*
```

in the *Find What* field and leave *Replace With* empty.

**Expression details**:

- `.*` - any char other than a newline, zero or more occurrences
- `Cost: 0` - a sequence of literal chars
- `\$` - a literal `$` symbol
- `.*` - any char other than a newline, zero or more occurrences
- `\R*` - zero or more linebreaks (any types, `\r` or `\r\n`, or `\n` only).

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped so much.